# Can both a 240V power supply and a 120V power supply, coming from a sauna heater's single power unit, go to the same outbuilding?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, conduit, nec

So the situation is as follows: I've found an electric sauna heater I want to use in the detached, outdoor sauna I'm building. The outdoor sauna is 55' away from the house, so I'm planning to bury PVC conduit 18" deep for the wire runs.

A wall-mounted "power unit" which needs to go inside the house (sensitive electronics can't freeze, apparently) receives 240V power from the main breaker panel in the house. The power unit then sends 240V power out to the heater. A data cable also runs between the power unit and a digital control unit, installed inside the house to turn the sauna and sauna room lights on/off. A separate data cable runs from a temperature sensor in the sauna hot room back to the power unit as well. This temp sensor data cable will need to be buried in conduit for the run from the sauna to the house separate from the power cables, kept >2" away from the power cables per manufacturer. The power unit also has a connection that provides the power to a 120V light circuit, controlled by the digital control unit.

My questions:
So, because the power unit is protected by the double-throw breaker, and is providing power for both the 240V run to the sauna heater AND the 120V run to the lights, will this been seen as a single circuit going to an outbuilding? Or will this count as two separate circuits?

Assuming they count as one circuit and I'm allowed to send them both to the sauna building, will the 240V and the 120V wire runs out to the sauna be allowed to be in the same conduit? Or will I need to run three conduits? (One for the temp sensor data cable, one for the 120V light supply, and one for the 240V heater supply?)

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: So there's a data circuit between electronics in the sauna and electronics at the controller.  Is every part of the data circuit *entirely contained* with enclosures suitable for AC mains wiring?

Comment: Can you give us links to the install instructions for this sauna?

Comment: Where are you located? Local codes can vary...

Comment: [http://www.finlandiasauna.com/manuals/cx30-cx45-manual.pdf](http://www.finlandiasauna.com/manuals/cx30-cx45-manual.pdf) 
Page 11, It's a CX30 controller to a Cylindro 7 (HPC7-U1).   

Minnesota.   
I don't have the data cable in hand, so I can't speak to its encloure situation.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need to run two conduits

The good news is that mixing 120 and 240V circuits in the same conduit is fine, and each of the mains circuits (light, aux, heater) in the mains conduit would be considered a "different use" for the purposes of NEC 225.30(D) since they're separately switched, so you can run all three mains circuits from the main building to the outbuilding instead of putting the power unit at the outbuilding.  You *should* be able to run the A1/A2 (thermal protector) wires in this conduit as well, since they also run to the heater itself alongside the other mains wiring.

However, you'll need to run the temperature sensor cable in a separate conduit; I called Finlandia Sauna tech support, and they insisted that the temp sensor cable be separated from mains wiring, so I doubt the insulation on it is rated for running alongside mains, and the temperature sensor's housing may not be mains-legal either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a single circuit a 220v circuit to the spa controller is all you have the mfg then can split that off and there are probably fuses or breakers on that circuit coming from the controller. As long as the equipment is listed and the instructions tell you to use the light it is part of the MFG assembly that you ran 1 circuit to and would be legal if you are under the jurisdiction of the NEC.
With listed equipment you shall follow the MFG instructions (this is true even when they conflict with the code).